# Having a nightmare with this nested for loop in terraform

Tags: python, for-loop, terraform

Terraform Map:

```
final_config = {for records in local.my_records : for record in records["records"] : record["name"] => record["limit_config"] if contains(record, "limit_config")}
```

Context: local.my_records is a list of map records, and I'm further trying to create a new map called final_config with key record["name"] and value record["limit_config"] if the record contains "limit_config".

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here with the for logic. I'm new to terraform, so unable to process the for loop. My Python code (which works) is like this:

```
limit = {}
for records in my_records:
    for record in records["records"]:
            if 'limit_config' in record:
                limit[record["name"]] = record["limit_config"]
```

Comment: And what happens when you try this?

Comment: Invalid 'for' expression

Extra characters after the end
of the 'for' expression.

Key expression is required
when building an object.
@TimRoberts

Comment: You did not provide exactly what `local.my_records` is.

Comment: If you're familiar with Python it might help to think about list and dict comprehensions rather than imperative `for` loops. Terraform's syntax has the clauses in a different order (the `for` goes at the front and the result expression comes after) but the way you'd use them is similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think the nesting has to be done like this:

```
final_config = { for record in 
   { for records in local.my_records : records['records'] } :
    record["name"] => record["limit_config"]
    if contains(record, "limit_config")        }
```

However, I don't have the ability to test this.

Comment: Thanks, @Tim. Would this logic work for Terraform nested for loop?

Error i got:
Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value. If you intended to given an attribute name containing periods or spaces, write the name in quotes to create a string literal.

Comment: I am trying to convert my python code into terraform nested for statements. The block which you gave me is still a Python syntax. @Tim Roberts

Comment: @Marcin

local.my_records is a list of map records

Something like:

[{'client': 'company-1',
  'records': [{'name': 'company-1.abc'},
{'client': 'company-2',
  'records': [{'name': 'company-2.abc'}]

Comment: Sorry, I did that because I thought that's what you were trying to do.  Your statement looks like (almost) Python.  Let me take another look.